# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Array

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, multer

I am trying to upload multiple images per request to Multer. Before using typescript it worked fine but now I am using typescript in my node app , when ill upload image or images this same error is thrown up

" [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Array
at Object.unlink (fs.js:1245:10)
at D:\PRACTICE-PROJECTS\MULTIPLE IMAGE SHARING\backend\dist\server.js:31:12
"

i tried working with fs.unlink too in my server.js file but I cannot understand the error. One more thing just posting texts request without images works fine so problem is surely with images.

server.ts

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Express } from "express";



const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");

const app: Express = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));

const fileRoutes = require("./ROUTES/fileRoutes");

app.use("/api/files", fileRoutes);


app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    res.status(404);
    res.json({ message: "ROUTE NOT FOUND" });

});

app.use((err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    console.log("FILES : " + req.files);

    if (req.files) {

        fs.unlink(req.files, () => { });
    }
    if (res.headersSent) {
        return next(err);
    }

    res.status(err.code || 500);
    res.json({ message: err.message || "SOMETHING WENT WRONG" });
});

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
        console.log("MONGOOSE CONNECTED");
    }

    catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            console.log("ERROR IS : " + err.message);
        }

    }


};

connectDB();


app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

fileRoutes.ts

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const postpics = require("../CONTROLLERS/fileControllers").postPics;
const fileUploader = require("../UPLOADER/multer");
const getpics = require("../CONTROLLERS/fileControllers").getPics;

router.get("/", getpics);
router.post("/upload", fileUploader.array("files"), postpics);

module.exports = router;
```

fileControllers.ts

```
const FILE = require("../MODELS/file");
import { RequestHandler } from "express";

const postPics: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {

   const recievedfiles: Express.Multer.File[] = req.files as Express.Multer.File[];
   const { title, price, description } = req.body;
   const files = recievedfiles.map((file: any) => file.path);



   let newImage = new FILE({
      title: title,
      price: parseFloat(price),
      description: description,
      file: files
   });

   try {
      newImage.save();
   }

   catch (err) {
      const error = new Error("SOMETHING WENT WRONG , CANT SAVE FILES");
      error.code = 500;
      console.log("ERROR IN UPLOAD : " + err);
      return next(error);

   }

   res.status(201).json({ message: "FILES UPLOADED SUCCESS" });

};

exports.postPics = postPics;
```

Comment: I fixed this error :     somehow typescript wont allow to fs.unlink multiple files at once which is allowed and work in vanilla js . So i did this to unlink files from my fileSystem.        After "if(req.files) " check in error middleware in server.ts add this :     const filess = (req.files as { path: string }[]).map((file) => file.path);

        for (let i = 0; i < filess.length; i++) {

            fs.unlink(filess[i], () => { });
        }